# Creating Mongo DB time series collection using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, npm, mongoose

Is there any npm package that can be used to create mongodb time series collection using node js?

I couldn't see any doc in **mongoose** npm package.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a package for that
USE

```
npm install mongoose-timeseries
```